# Can I re-style google map's infowindows to look less crappy?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The chunky speech bubble things look pretty crap in my opinion, i'd like something much tidier and more minimal.

Are there any native ways to change the info box style without manually replacing the elements with js each time an infowindow is shown (clumsy)?

I'm using google maps api v3.

Answer (score 45):

I'm currently working on a project and had a similar requirement.  I used this:

Infobox from:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

It did exactly what I needed it to.  I does require minor JS changes, but works pretty well.

Good luck!